# How to convert strings in a text file into integers and store them in another file?

Tags: python, file, file-io

How could I read a text file with the following list of items:

```
    milk
    eggs 
    bacon
```

and convert them into integers by adding up their ord() values and store them in another file or store them in the same file by overwriting its values?

So far I have:

```
with open("grocery_items.txt") as f:
     items = [word.strip() for word in f]

text_file = open("item_ordvals.txt", "w+")


c = 2 
for i in items:
    for k in i:
    result = ord(i[0])
    result = result * c + ord(i[k])

text_file.close()
```

I read each item from a file named "grocery_items.txt" and stored it into a list called items. 
What essentially Im trying to do is get a unique value for each word in the file by multiplying the first letter of a word in the items list by a constant c and then adding it to the ord values of the rest of the letters in the word. What am I doing wrong so far?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: Im sorry abou that. I changed it.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). Note that Python provides quite a good one: [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash).

Comment: On top of that, your method would result to the same number for any xyyyyyy, where x is the first letter and yyyyyy and permutation of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line for line in f.read().split('\n')]

numbers = [[ord(character) for character in word] for word in lines] # Use list comprehension to find ord() of each character.
print([word for word in lines][0], sum(numbers[0]))
print([word for word in lines][1], sum(numbers[1]))
print([word for word in lines][2], sum(numbers[2]))
```

list.txt:

```
milk
eggs
bacon
```

Output:

```
milk 429
eggs 422
bacon 515
```

What is it doing:

1. First it is opening the file `list.txt`
2. Uses Python's list comprehension syntax to find out ord(character) of each character.
3. Takes sum of all values in list and prints them

**NOTE**

The list comprehension is equivalent to this:

```
numbers = []
for word in lines:
    for character in word:
        numbers.append(ord(character))
```